# How can I make this code appear with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="Activity" class="rep_tb0" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="rep_tr0" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="rep_td0" style="width: 100%" id="ActivityLog">Activity Log<br /><br /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like for it to be invisible when the web page is opened and then for it to show visible when I run some javascript. Is there an easy way to do this with jQuery? How can I make it invisible and make it so no space is reserved for it when the web page starts up?

Comment: On what condition are you looking to make the div appear? Click, mouseover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:none;` style to hide it:

```
<div id="Activity" class="rep_tb0" style="width: 100%; display:none;">
    <div class="rep_tr0" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="rep_td0" style="width: 100%" id="ActivityLog">Activity Log<br /><br /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To show with jquery:

```
$('#Activity').show();
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/s2bBw/1/

Answer (score 0):

To make it invisible, add `display: none;` to the `style` attribute - or better yet add it to a class. On what condition would you like to make it appear, mouseover, click, etc?

This should work for a click event:

HTML

```
<div id="Activity" class="rep_tb0" style="width: 100%; display: none;">
    <div class="rep_tr0" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="rep_td0" style="width: 100%" id="ActivityLog">Activity Log<br /><br /></div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="show">Show div</a>
```

JS

```
$("#show").click(function() {
    $("#Activity").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to hide on load, do this

```
$(function(){
    $("#Activity").hide();
});
```

to make it visible do

```
$("#Activity").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the div on pageload like this:

```
$(document).ready(
  function{
    $("#Activity").hide();
  }
);
```

And then unhide when you need to show it.

```
$("#Activity").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### html

```
<div id="Activity" class="rep_tb0" style="width: 100%: display:none;">
    <div class="rep_tr0" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="rep_td0" style="width: 100%" id="ActivityLog">Activity Log<br /><br /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### css

```
#Activity{
    display:none;
}
```

#### script

```
function showThat(){
    $("#Activity").show()
}
```

if u want to make it visible use `showThat()` function or `$("#Activity").show()`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show it when you run some javascript you can either put the:

```
 $('#Activity').show();
```

in that javascript:

```
function run(){
  some code;
  $('#Activity').show();
}
```

or put it in a function, and call the function from anywhere you like:

```
function showActivity(){
    $('#Activity').show();
}
$().ready(function() {
    showActivity();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can include it in your jquery script and use append to put it where you want, search here: [enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Something along the lines:

```
    var code = "<div id="Activity" class="rep_tb0" style="width: 100%">
                 <div class="rep_tr0" style="width: 100%">
                 <div class="rep_td0" style="width: 100%" 
                 id="ActivityLog">Activity Log<br /><br />
                </div>
                 </div>
                  </div>"

$("element_you_want_to_append_to").append(code);
```